# Different Types of Navigation in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

What is the difference between these two Navigation paradigms in Xamarin.Forms?

```
await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new Dashboard());

await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new NavigationPage(new Dashboard()));
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## What is a Modal Page

`Navigation.PushModalAsync` will cause the new `Xamarin.Forms.Page` to appear Modally, meaning its animation will start from the bottom of the screen, covering the previous current page and it will not contain a back-button.

On iOS, a user will not be able to swipe-left to return to the previous page.

Android users are able to use the hardware back button to dismiss a modal page.

Modal pages are useful when you want the user to make a conscious decision to dismiss the page.

**Example**

When an iOS user is filling out a form and they swipe left to go back, does it save the form or discard the form? It is unclear to the user. To make the UX more intuitive, you should display the form modally

## UI Differences

Using `await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new Dashboard());` will display the `Dashboard` Page Modally, but the new Page *will not* have a NavigationBar.

[image]

Using `await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new NavigationPage(new Dashboard()));` will also display the `Dashboard` Page Modally, but the new Page *will* have a NavigationBar.

[image]

Sample App Source Code: https://github.com/brminnick/XamList

#### Edit

[@AlessandroCaliaro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4399386/alessandro-caliaro) and I had a good discussion in the comments of his answer, below:

It's important to note that [`Xamarin.Forms.INavigation`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.INavigation/) uses two different stacks, `ModalStack` and `NavigationStack`. `Navigation.PushModalAsync` adds a `Page` to the `ModalStack` and `Navigation.PushAsync` adds a `Page` to the `NavigationStack`.

And to pop a `Page` from the `ModalStack`, you need to use `Navigation.PopModalAsync()`, whereas you would use `Navigation.PopAsync()` to remove a `Page` from the `NavigationStack`.

Comment: Thanks. Sometimes await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new Dashboard());  went to break mode while Android debugging.? Anyway nice explained. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @Ganeshgm7! Sure, happy to look into the debugging problem! Let’s mark this question as answered and open a new question where we can focus on that question 

Comment: I think this answer may works but could have some problems https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/111476/why-header-is-being-duplicated

Comment: @AlessandroCaliaro No. The forum post you linked is about Navigation.PushAsync(). This StackOverflow question is about Navigation.PushModalAsync().

Comment: You do not need an instance of NavigationPage to perform PushModelAsync()

There is nothing wrong with hosting a NavigationPage instance in a Modal because the Modal is independent of the original NavigationPage. The better question is around why you are trying to do that? UI/UX guidelines would have me question why you want a navbar in a modal, there is probably a better UX way to do whatever you want to accomplish

Answer (score -1):

The first, push a page in a "modal" way (without navigation bar on the top)
the second... is an error because you try to add a navigationpage to a navigationstack, but I think it is not possible....

Comment: Sometimes I am getting break mode while navigation with first line. With the second line it's works fine. I don't know the purpose. Thant's asked here.

Comment: It is valid to use `await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new NavigationPage(new Dashboard()));`. This is the only way to display a NavigationBar on a Modal Page.

Comment: @BrandonMinnick take a look to this... I think I am not wrong https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/111476/why-header-is-being-duplicated

Comment: That forum post is about PushAsync. This question is about PushModalAsync.

Comment: Problem is not between PushAsync and PushModalAsync, but should exists only one instance of NavigationPage (root)

Comment: @AlessandroCaliaro Xamarin.Forms.INavigation uses two different stacks, `ModalStack` and `NavigationStack`. `PushModalAsync()` adds to the `ModalStack` and `PushAsync()` adds to the `NavigationStack`. https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.INavigation/

Comment: You do not need an instance of `NavigationPage` to perform `PushModelAsync()`: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/navigation/modal/

There is nothing wrong with hosting a `NavigationPage` instance in a `Modal` because the `Modal` is independent of the original `NavigationPage`. The better question is around why you are trying to do that? UI/UX guidelines would have me question why you want a navbar in a modal, there is probably a better UX way to do whatever you want to accomplish