# Xamarin Forms - How to pass data from a modal page back to parent page using Viewmodels

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms, viewmodel

I have two pages: `MainPage` and `FilterPage`(modal page).
with their respective Viewmodels: `MainViewModel` and `FilterViewModel`.

In `MainPage` I have a listview that's populated with data from an API. The data is passed to the `FilterPage` where it is filtered by some specific criteria. In the end a new list is created which is assigned to the binded variable of the listview. What I noticed is that after the modal page closes the listview's items arent updated. What is the proper way to do this?

**`Model`:**

```
public class Multilist
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }    
        public string Date { get; set; } 
        public string Status { get; set; }
        public string Customer { get; set; }

    }
```

**`MainViewModel`:**

```
public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged 
{

private IList<Multilist> mainList = new List<Multilist>();
        public IList<Multilist> MainList
        {
            get => mainList;
            set
            {
                if (value == mainList)
                    return;
                mainList = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }


#region INotifyPropertyChanged
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
        {
            var changed = PropertyChanged;
            if (changed == null)
                return;

            changed.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
        #endregion



public MainViewModel(INavigation navigation)
        {
            this._navigation = navigation; 

            Task.Run(async () => await GetData());

            GotoFilterPageCommand = new AsyncCommand(GotoFilterPage);            

        }

private async Task GetData()
        {
            
            //Gets data from API
            MainList = data;

        }

private async Task GotoFilterPage()
        {
            await this._navigation.PushModalAsync(new FilterPage(MainList.ToList()), true);
            
        }


}
```

**`FilterViewModel`:**

```
public class FilterViewModel : INotifyPropertyChange
    {

public List<Multilist> OldList { get; set; }

private IList<Multilist> mainList = new List<Multilist>();
        public IList<Multilist> MainList
        {
            get => mainList;
            set
            {
                if (value == mainList)
                    return;
                mainList = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }


#region INotifyPropertyChanged
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
        {
            var changed = PropertyChanged;
            if (changed == null)
                return;

            changed.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
        #endregion


        public FilterViewModel(List<Multilist> oldlist)
        {
            Oldlist = oldlist;
            SomeCommand = new AsyncCommand(SomeTask);


        }


private async Task SomeTask()
        {
            // Some code here
            CreateNewList(OldList);
        }

private async Task CreateNewList(List<Multilist> oldlist)
        {
            //Some code here --> newMainList
            
            pageA.MainList = newMainList;
            await App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PopModalAsync();
        }



}
```

**The listview in `MainPage`:**

```
<ListView x:Name="TestListView"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding MainList}"                     
                  Grid.Row="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                  HasUnevenRows="True"
                  >
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <StackLayout Padding="0,0,0,1">
                                <Grid VerticalOptions="Fill" Padding="10">

                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="60"></RowDefinition>

                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>

                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Title}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" />
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Date}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" />
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Customer}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" />
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Status}" HorizontalTextAlignment="End" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" />

                                </Grid>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

Comment: are both VM's using the same instance of `MainList`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Xamarin Forms: Pass Information from Modal to Origin Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71280349/xamarin-forms-pass-information-from-modal-to-origin-page)

Comment: @Jason Yes, both viewmodels inherit from a base viewmodel where MainList is declared.

Comment: I asked if they were the same **instance**.  The code you've provided doesn't clearly illustrate what you're doing.  See [mcve]

Comment: @Amjad S. I couldn't make it work. In my case I have two pages with two viewmodels. The logic is that I get a list from an API with some data. This is displayed in the listview of page A and it works fine. In page A, there is also a button which opens the (modal) page B. Then, the user can activate certain filters to shrink the original list and update the listview.

Comment: @Jason Im not sure If I can answer your question. From what I've seen `MainList` data is updated correctly. However when the modal page closes nothing changes in the parent's page listview (that's binded with 'MainList' ).

Comment: You need to post a [mcve].  Just two snippets of VM is not enough to illustrate what you are doing.

Comment: @Jason I edited the question and added some more details.

Comment: @michchou the beauty of MVVM is that there no rule that says that your view can't have one or more viewmodels. In your case, you can perfectly invoke more than one view on your page. So, you can perfectly share a common viewmodel between the parent and the child.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Singleton to make a global instance for both `MainViewModel` and  `FilterViewModel`.

I make a simple example for your reference.

Model:

```
 public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
  public class PersonViewModel
{
    #region Singleton Pattern
    private PersonViewModel()
    {
        Persons = new ObservableCollection<Person>()
        {
            new Person(){ Name="A"},
            new Person(){ Name="A2"},
            new Person(){ Name="A3"},
            new Person(){ Name="A4"},
        };
    }
    public static PersonViewModel Instance { get; } = new PersonViewModel();
    #endregion
    private ObservableCollection<Person> _person;
    public ObservableCollection<Person> Persons
    {
        get { return _person; }
        set { _person = value; }
    }
}
```

Page24: //MainPage

```
 <StackLayout>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding MainList}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Name}"></Label>                               
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
        <Button Text="Navigate To FilterPage" Clicked="Button_Clicked"> 
     </Button>
    </StackLayout>
```

Page24 Code behind:

```
public Page24()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.BindingContext = new Page24ViewModel();
    }

    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Navigation.PushAsync(new FilterPage());
    }
```

Page24ViewModel://MainViewModel

```
public class Page24ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private PersonViewModel _personViewModel;

    public Page24ViewModel()
    {
        _personViewModel = PersonViewModel.Instance;

    }
    private ObservableCollection<Person> mainList;
    public ObservableCollection<Person> MainList
    {
        get { return _personViewModel.Persons; }
        set
        {
            mainList = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

FilterPage:

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="Name:"></Label>
            <Entry x:Name="entry"></Entry>
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button x:Name="btn_Add" Text="Add" Clicked="btn_Add_Clicked"></Button>
            <!--<Button x:Name="btn_Delete" Text="Delete" Clicked="btn_Delete_Clicked"></Button>-->
        </StackLayout>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding MainList}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Name}"></Label>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

FilterPage code behind:

```
 private PersonViewModel _personViewModel;
    public FilterPage()//modal page
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.BindingContext = new FilterViewModel();
    }

    private void btn_Add_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _personViewModel = PersonViewModel.Instance;
        _personViewModel.Persons.Add(new Person() { Name = entry.Text });
    }
```

FilterViewModel:

```
 public class FilterViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private PersonViewModel _personViewModel;

    public FilterViewModel()
    {
        _personViewModel = PersonViewModel.Instance;

    }
    private ObservableCollection<Person> newMainList;
    public ObservableCollection<Person> MainList
    {
        get { return _personViewModel.Persons; }
        set
        {
            newMainList = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Comment: Wendy thank you very much for putting the effort. I really appreciate it. I tried to use ObservableCollection instead of List, I used the instance too as well as navigation instead of modal but unfortunately nothing changed...

Comment: Have you tried my code? What's wrong with it? Please use the `ObservableCollection<Person>` instead of IList<T>. For your update, what is the class type of your itemsource? And what does `as well as navigation instead of modal` mean?

Comment: Your code works fine, I run it in a separate project. In my case however the data that I get from the API is in List form. I tried to  replace `IList` with `ObservableCollection` but the problem still exists. I also tried to make FilterPage open as a [navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47485426/different-types-of-navigation-in-xamarin-forms) page but again nothing changed as I was suspecting.

Comment: The logic is that I get a list from an API with some data. This is displayed in the listview of `MainPage` and it works fine. In `MainPage` , there is also a button which opens `FilterPage`. Then, the user can select certain filters to shrink the original list and update the listview. From what I noticed, the `MainList` updates with the new data normally, but as soon as `FilterPage` closes the binded data returns to the original that was acquired from the API. You can take a look at the question which I updated and maybe have a better understanding.

Comment: Use the ViewModel(something like the code i provided) to get the data from API. Do not get the data from `MainViewModel` directly. It would cover the data when you reload this model. Put the data to instance. And then change the instance via `PersonViewModel`.

Comment: Wendy I was updating the `ObservableCollection` in the wrong way before... I finally made it work. Thank you very much! You were a great help!